# Simple Inference with Dataproperty in Graphdb

Tags: owl, graphdb

I´m not an expert, but I had no answers with simple GRAPHDB query. I created in Protege a small ontology:

```
CLASS VarValue
       SUBCLASS1 - HighVarValue
       SUBCLASS2 - LowVarValue
```

The class `HighVarValue` has a general Class axiom:
`varDATA some xsd:float[>= 0.5f] SubClassOf HighVarValue`

The class `LowVarValue` has a general Class axiom:
`varDATA some xsd:float[< 0.5f] SubClassOf HighVarValue`

The instance of the class `VarValue` has a value of `100.0f` with `varDATA` dataProperty (image 2).

The inference with Protege (image 3) is OK to the simple query:

```
select ?x WHERE
{
     ?x a :HighVarValue .
}
```

But, using GRAPHDDB with RuleSet OWL2-QL or OWL2-RL, the result of the same query is empty.

Am I missing something? Thanks a lot.

[Subclass HighVarValue checking the value of VarValue instance:actualValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsewe.png)

[Instance actualValue with dataProperty varDATA=100.0f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzNa3.png)

[After reasoner, we can see: actualValue rdf:type HighVarvalue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i82fQ.png)

Comment: *"The following constructs are not supported in OWL 2 QL: • existential quantification to a class expression or a data range (**ObjectSomeValuesFrom** and **DataSomeValuesFrom**) in the subclass position"*.

Comment: Absolutely correct what StanislavKralin is saying, the axiom `varData some xsd:float [>=0.5] SubClassOf HighVarValue` is not supported in OWL QL profile. In OWL RL the existential restriction as subclass is supported, but a faceted datatype not: `DataRange := Datatype | DataIntersectionOf
`

Comment: Apart from the above, the GraphDb rule engine does not support datatype reasoning, e.g. there are no primitives to express comparison except equality nor there are other means to fetch literals's datatype so rules deriving the intended conclusions could not be written for it.